# sscanf 1 byte hex data without overflow

Tags: c, embedded, overflow, scanf

I need to scan a hex representation of 6 bytes data and store it in a 6 byte array.

Please note I am in an embedded system so every byte count.

Using sscanf this way :

```
uint8_t buf[6];
char hex[13] = "123456789ABC";
sscanf(hex, "%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X", &buf[0], &buf[1], &buf[2], &buf[3], &buf[4], &buf[5]);
```

is overflowing because each %02X specifier load in a uint32_t.

- %02lX will load in a uint32_t
- %02hX will load in a uint16_t

Is there a specifier that load in a uint8_t ? (I don't find it anywhere)

Is there another way of doing this ?

I tried to do :

```
sscanf(hex, "%08lX%04hX", &buf[0], &buf[4]);
```

this does not overflow, but as I am on little endian structure, the order is mixed up...

Comment: Does it need to be represented in big endian structure? What do you mean the order is messed up?

Comment: have you tried unsigned char? - aka %c

Comment: the code is loading into a 6byte buffer.  suggest loading using '%c' rather than '%02x'.

Comment: Not all embedded systems are severely resource constrained so the one does not follow the other; you should quantify your constraints more specifically.  On the face of it if you were truly that resource constrained, you would not use sscanf() in the first instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Please note I am in an embedded system so every byte count.

If that is the case then sscanf is probably ill-advised; its stack usage and code space will dwarf any saving you might perceive in using the smallest possible data type.  Consider:

```
uint8_t hexdigit( char hex )
{
    return (hex <= '9') ? hex - '0' : 
                          toupper(hex) - 'A' + 10 ;
}

uint8_t hexbyte( const char* hex )
{
    return (hexdigit(*hex) << 4) | hexdigit(*(hex+1)) ;
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
char hex[13] = "123456789ABC";

for( int b = 0; b < 6; b++ )
{
    buf[b] = hexbyte( &hex[b * 2] ) ;
}
```

If you must use `sscanf()` but your library does not support the `hh` format specifier qualifier (as many embedded or older C libraries may not), then you can use an intermediate integer:

```
char hex[13] = "123456789ABC";

for( int b = 0; b < 6; b++ )
{
    unsigned byte ;

    sscanf( &hex[b * 2], "%02X", &byte ) ;
    buf[b] = (unit8_t)byte ;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer on that topic. I do not understand the [b * 1]. Can anyone explain?

Comment: @Noel ; It is an error or type.  Only took nearly 4 years for anyone to spot it!  Fixed it.

Comment: This is very true, I checked 2 "embedded" implementations and they were using respectively 100 and 500 bytes of stack....

Comment: It was surprising for me to see that `hh` was indeed not supported in my case too (`gnu-arm-none-eabi` 7.3.1) ... Is there any particular reason why?

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür : because standalone GCC implementations do not use the POSIX dependent gnu libc C library, and you are probably using Newlib or other C library.  That is to say, it is about the C library, not the compiler.

Answer (score 9):

You want to use `%02hhX` on an array of unsigned char. (So `uint8_t` is fine)

Comment: It's buried and might depend on which set of man pages you have. At http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf, check out the first bit under the section titled "The length modifier". It's a big man page, printf format strings are complex.

Comment: If he is that severely resource constrained, he is unlikely to be using Linux, so the man page reference may not be relevant.  The `hh` format modifier was introduced in ISO C99, and many embedded libraries use "cut-down" stdio implementations in any case, so it may not be available.  @moquette31, you should consult the library documentation for your specific tool-chain.

Comment: Win32/64 platform for some reason will not write a single byte in case of `%02hhx`: https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus/pull/97/files